# Possible to call stateful function in a class in Python?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, metaclass

Is it possible to directly set a certain value and get it in a class by any mean(inheritance, metaclass, class decorator) in Python? class B must not be polluted by set('a') in A.

```py
import sys


class A:
    set('a')
    get()
    # -> 'a'

    print(sys.modules[__name__])
    # => <module '__main__'>


class B:
    get()
    # -> None
```

Comment: What exactly are `set` and `get` doing?

Comment: As for the class `A`, `set('a')` saves `'a'` of `A` class(but not an instance of it) to memory. `get()` gets the saved `'a'` from the memory. It doesn't have to remove `'a'` from the memory while `get`ting. if `set()` is called twice, the first value is overwritten with the second one.

While in B, `get()` tries to get any value saved for class `B`. However, it doesn't find in any value. Because, `set()` is not called in `B`.

Comment: That tells me what you *want* them to do; I asked what they are actually *doing*: show the definitions.

Comment: actually, it's arbitrary what `set` and `get` do. But, assuming that what they do affects the way of implementation for an answer in Python, this is an example;

```
a = None;

def set(value):
    a = value;

def get():
    return a;
```

But, this example obviously doesn't work for my first example. Does this answer your question?

Comment: `set` is creating a local variable; it's not changing the value of the global variable `a` or of a class attribute of `A`.

Comment: You still haven't asked a clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know what you are doing, yes, it is possible to set values with programmatic names in a class body, and retrieve then, and have these values restricted to that class body.

All you have to do is to use the`locals()` call to get the namespace dictionary, and use that dictionary to hold your values:

```py
class A:
    locals()["key"] = "a"
    print(locals()["key"] )
```

This will print "a", 
and obviously, this value won't be part of a class B namespace.

If you want just to store values without associating then
with a name, the `stackfull` project provide a
`push` and `pop` calls that will behave just like 
you proposed in your example - 
but if you try  a `pop()` withour a previous `push` 
in the same scope, you will get an error due to
a stack underflow:

```py
In [4]: !pip install stackfull                                                                 
Collecting stackfull
...
Successfully installed stackfull-1.0.0


In [5]: from stackfull import push, pop                                                        

In [6]: class A: 
   ...:     push("a") 
   ...:     push("b") 
   ...:     print(pop()) 
   ...:     print(pop()) 
   ...:                                                                                        
b
a
In [7]: class B: 
   ...:     pop() 
   ...:   
...
StackUnderflowError:
```

(Disclaimer -  I am the author of the stackfull package. I never really needed
anything beyond what is already there, so it  has not been updated in a long time - and with the "walrus" operator in Python 3.8, it is no longer that useful)

Ok - so I listed this because it resembles the code in your question, but chances are you need something more mainstream, like writing your code in methods, and set instance attributes.

Comment: thanks very much. I came up with some ideas of implementations from your suggestions :)

An assigned value for `locals()["key"]` in the first example you suggested will be a function in my case as you might expect. Do you come up with any side-effect by updating locals? One thing I do is it could overwrite existing functions in a class body.

Answer (score 0):

These two independent classes don't reference each other, so as long as you don't pass the same object to both, then neither will 'pollute' the other. To set a value and get a value on an object, you could use something like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.letter = None
    def set_value(self, letter):
        self.letter = letter
    def get_value(self):
        return self.letter if self.letter else '(none set)'

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.letter = None
    def set_value(self, letter):
        self.letter = letter
    def get_value(self):
        return self.letter if self.letter else '(none set)'

>>> a = A()
>>> aa = A()
>>> b = B()
>>> a.set_value('z')
>>> print(f'values in a, aa, and b are: {a.get_value()}, {aa.get_value()}, {b.get_value()}')
values in a, aa, and b are: z, (none set), (none set)
```

So as you can see, setting the `a` object's letter doesn't set it in `b` (a different class), or in `aa`, which is a different instance of the same A class. Hope that helps!

Happy Coding!

Comment: This is unfortunately different from what I asked for. I wanted an equivalent without creating instances of A and B.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really tell what you are asking for. You can get and set values on a class, and it isn't polluted by another class. "set a certain value and get it in a class by any mean" isn't informative. Setting a value, and getting it back again isn't complicated, so I think you are probably just lacking some additional details on the specifics of what you require. Feel free to add more to the question.

Comment: My code tells what I want ... Metaprogramming and instance-level programming are two very different scheme. Please find if your code works for my code. thanks anyways